# iptables input, output rules

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, iptables

I need help with this iptables rules. I don't understand why is needed INPUT rule for port 8080

server with public ip 123.123.123.123

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

iptables -I INPUT 1 -p all -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -s 123.123.123.123 -j ACCEPT
```

when I disable INPUT rule pro 8080, firewall will block port 8080

when SERVER try open GET 123.123.123.123:8080 fails! (responce timeout) why?

why it didn't enable rule ESTABLISHED,RELATED ???

Answer (score 1):

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p all -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

^ this works for connections that already are established, so id doesn't catch any new connections.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -s 123.123.123.123 -j ACCEPT
```

^ and this one catch anything what's trying to send TCP packets to 123.123.123.123:8080 and accepts it.
If you can't connect to that service when this entry is not present is because there can be something furthermore in your chain which catch the trafic and makes `-j REJECT` or `-j DROP`

...or you have REJECT or DROP policy on this chain.

check `iptables -L INPUT` to check that and `iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT` to change it.

One easy way to check what is going on on your chain is to check `iptables -L -n -v`. The verbose parameter will give you amount of pkts and bytes for every rule so watching it you can figure out if your rule is catching anything.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, solution is not to enable INPUT ACCEPT

but add enabletion for all connection from server to self

```
iptables -I INPUT 2 -p all -m state --state NEW -s 123.123.123.123 -j ACCEPT
```

I didn't reliaze that new connection from server is valid (OUTPUT is enabled) but firewall then get's NEW connection to INPUT ... that's not enabled by default

Comment: It's usually a good practice to have DROP policy and use rules to be aware what you're going to ACCEPT. Your question was 'why first rule doesn't catch it and it doesn't work without second one. It's your choice to select best approach and solution for your needs.